# find out if the user's email found in database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is how I want it to find out about email find in the database if it do to the come up and say hello this email is busy try a different or similar.

I expect:
it comes and find out about the email found in my database if it does it must give the user an answer.

if it does not exist in the database, it just create user as normal.

Right now get it to 0, there is no email in the database or look like but it still says that email is registered, but if I type 1 in place of 0 then I can create as many email I bother.

```
}
    else
        {
            $email_1 = $_post["email"];
            $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `bruger` WHERE email='$email_1'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($resut) > 0)
            {


            $pb = null;

            include "fun_filer/img/class.upload.php";
            $handle = new Upload($_FILES["file"]);

            if($handle->uploaded)
            {
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_y = 75;
                $handle->image_x = 75;
                $handle->Process("images/bruger");
                $pb = $handle->file_dst_name;
            }

            if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `bruger` (`rank`, `email`, `adgangskode`, `navn`, `efternavn`, `profil_img`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('isssss', $rank, $email, $adgangskode, $navn, $efternavn, $profil_img);

                $rank = 1;
                $email = $_POST["email"];
                $adgangskode = sha1($_POST["password_adgangskode_1"]);
                $navn = $_POST["fornavn"];
                $efternavn = $_POST["efternavn"];
                $profil_img = $pb;

                $stmt->execute();

                $navn = $_POST["navn"];
                $til = $_POST["email"];
                $password = $_POST["password_adgangskode_1"];


                $fra = "Hello.com - Opret bruger <" . "info@hello.com" . ">";
                $til = $_POST["email"];
                $emne = "Velkommen til Hello.com";

                $besked = file_get_contents('mail_opret.php');

                $besked = str_replace("%%navn", $navn, $besked);
                $besked = str_replace("%%brugernavn", $til, $besked);
                $besked = str_replace("%%password", $password, $besked);

                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \n";
                $headers .= "From: " . $fra . "\n";

                mail($til, $emne, $besked, $headers);

                ?>
                <div class="article-main-content">
                <div class="alert-message" style="background-color:#77b01e;"><span class="icon-text">&#10003;</span><span class="alert-content">Din bruger er blevet opret og du få en email fra os <a href="#" class="destroy-button"></a></div>
                </div>
                <?php

                $stmt->close();


            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <div class="article-main-content">
            <div class="alert-message" style="background-color:#c22525;"><span class="icon-text">&#9888;</span><span class="alert-content">Email Findes på hjemmesiden</span><a href="#" class="destroy-button"></a></div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

When I located it on 1 so, input and everything incredibly well.

Comment: Seems like it should be `mysqli_num_rows($result)`

Comment: Thanks. Now I just have clearly such that the gain out of it exists in the database or not. because right now if I put 1 or 0 on so it does not work as I want it.

Comment: Are you saying that it *always* says `mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0`?

Comment: Yes such a stand on right now. if I try to create as it will appear with an error on the page: (but it does not create the database so it's good or what?

Comment: Just a word of warning: Your first query is susceptible to SQL injections. Be sure to either change it to be escaped, or preferably use a prepared statement like you did in the second query.

Comment: @j883376 Do you have a way you can show me it on '. as I understand it is probably better?

Comment: @j883376 not only that, but his `mail()` function can be abused by spammers to send mail from his host.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a unique key in the Sql table itself. However, is it only a mistake that you wrote 'resut'?